# Merge multiple fonts into one font in Google docs

Tags: google-docs

I have a report in a Google doc, that is compiled out of many smaller sections which were written by different people.

Thus there is no standard heading1, heading2, body, font sizes. (For example, some body text has 12pt, some 11pt, some 13pt.)

What I want to do is to somehow automate the process of converting font of 11pt, 12pt, 13pt all into 12pt and all font of 14pt 18pt into 18pt and so on.

Is there any way I can do this in an automated way?

Comment: I ended up confused while I was try to edit this, can you clarify what you wanna do?

Comment: Now it should much more clear I believe.I had used a mobile to post it hence a few autocorrect mistakes.

Comment: If it's not too long, the easiest path might be to convert a copy to all plain text without any font attributes or style, then hand-edit the headings etc. by a single style template. Keep the original doc for comparison.

Comment: That surely would have been feasible had it not been 120 pages!